# How to reference package from Conan recipe on github

Tags: c++, git, build, conan

I have a C++ (Windows, MSVC) project and I'm using Conan to manage external dependencies. So far, I've been adding dependencies by including them under `[requires]` in my *conanfile.txt*. I'm relatively new to Conan.

Now I'm trying to reference the following package:
https://github.com/firefalcom/bgfx-conan

This package is not available on any remotes as far as I can tell. What is the correct way to install, build, and add a Conan package recipe like this to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to clone the repository locally, then run:

`conan create .`

To install the package. Then you can reference it in your `conanfile.txt` based on the package name and version specified in the *conanfile.py*. So for me, it is `bgfx/7188`.

Comment: To speed up your installing process, you can upload your packages in Bintray and download from anywhere: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/bintray/uploading_bintray.html.

Comment: If you want to store private packages, both recipes and pre-compiled binaries for your desired configurations, to avoid re-building (``conan create``) packages again and again, you could run your own instance of ArtifactoryCE, which is completely free.